A question on locating the roots using the triangle inequality
I also wanted to solve this by triangles inequality.
Prove that $z^3+2z+4=0$ doesn't have a root in the unit circle?

Which functions did you choose to apply Rouché's theorem?

By contradiction, assume $w$ is a root that lies in the unit circle. Since $w$ is a root, $w^3+2w+4=0$. And since $w$ lies in the unit circle, $|w|< 1$. Using the reverse triangle inequality,
$$|w^3+2w+4|=|4-(-2w-w^3)|\geq 4-|2 w+w^3|> 4-3=1.$$
Notice that if $|w|< 1$ then $|2 w+w^3|\leq 2|w|+|w|^{3}< 3$.

It is impossible to have $w^3+2w+4=0$ and $|w^3+2w+4|>1$.
